# перенос данных на новую строку Datacol

Tags: парсер

Нужна помощь, как сделать перенос на новую строку в Datacol 5.54 при замене? Нужно с новой строки каждое поле характеристик сделать в прайсе, решения не нашел. Пробовал подставлять \n, но не срабатывает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Часто спрашивают, как сделать перенос? Как добавить пробел? Все очень просто.
Вот список стандартных так сказать макросов, на которые можно заменять:

```
%NL% : перенос строки
%SPACE% : пробел
%TAB% : табуляция
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! %NL% не срабатывал в моем случае, о стандартных заменах мне было известно. Решил с помощью замены